# Is it possible to have a 2 dimension array as a result type from a map in CLisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

is it possible  in C-Lisp to collect the results of a map into an array with 2 dimensions? how would I reference this array in the function?

I've tried things like,

```
(map  'Array'(3 3)  #'somefunction  sequence)
```

or

```
(map '(simple-array T (3 3))  #'somefunction  sequence)
```

and was not successful.

Of course the sequence i'm starting from have the same number of total elements of the result array i wish to obtain

Comment: Hello FYI "C-Lisp" refers to a specific implementation of the "CL" language. Other implementations include SBCL, CCL, ECL, LispWorks…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this is to use displaced arrays and `map-into`.  Here's an over-simple example:

```
(defun map-array (f a &rest make-array-kws &key &allow-other-keys)
  ;; Map F over A, which can be any array, returning a new array with
  ;; the same shape as A.  Keyword arguments get passwd to MAKE-ARRAY
  ;; of the result array.  This may not handle things like fill
  ;; pointers well or at all.
  (let ((r (apply #'make-array (array-dimensions a)
                   make-array-kws)))
    (map-into
     (make-array (array-total-size r)
                 :element-type (array-element-type r)
                 :displaced-to r)
     f
     (make-array (array-total-size a)
                 :element-type (array-element-type a)
                 :displaced-to a))
    r))
```

Answer (score 3):

No. According to the hyperspec (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_map.htm#map), the result type specifier has to be a sequence type. Multi-dimensional arrays are not sequence types. Of course, you could write a function to do what you want, but it cannot be directly accomplished with the `map` function.

Here's how you might make your own:

```
(defun map-to-array (fn sequence w h &optional (type t))
  (assert (<= (length sequence) (* w h)) (w h) "Result array too small.")
  (let ((result (make-array (list w h)
                            :element-type type))
        (x -1)
        (y 0))
    (map nil
         (lambda (e)
           (incf x)
           (when (= x w)
             (setf x 0)
             (incf y))
           (setf (aref result x y)
                 (funcall fn e)))
         sequence)
    result))
```

Comment: Note that the second argument called `sequence` must actually be a `vector`.